# SQL Server: why does sp_executesql try to convert my Key column datatype?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a login function in ASP.NET Core. I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and Entity Framework Core with a code-first approach.

When I call:

```
await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)
```

I use SQL server profiler and get this query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [AspNetUsers] ([Id], 
        [AccessFailedCount], [ConcurrencyStamp], [Email], 
        [EmailConfirmed], [LockoutEnabled], [LockoutEnd], [NormalizedEmail], 
        [NormalizedUserName], [PasswordHash], [PhoneNumber], [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
        [SecurityStamp], [TwoFactorEnabled], [UserName])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14);',

N'@p0 nvarchar(450),@p1 int,@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(256),
@p4 bit,@p5 bit,@p6 datetimeoffset(7),@p7 nvarchar(256),@p8 nvarchar(256),
@p9 nvarchar(4000),@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p11 bit,@p12 nvarchar(4000),@p13 bit,@p14 nvarchar(256)',

@p0=N'00ca2ac7-661d-4bc4-a967-4bf214fa9a29',     -- This is the problem

@p1=0,@p2=N'43e70141-6df1-4fb8-9c03-19d252f02c21',
@p3=N'caiduoiconmeo1999@gmail.com',
@p4=0,@p5=1,@p6=NULL,@p7=N'sample@GMAIL.COM',@p8=N'HUU',
@p9=N'AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEL42no/kcGAe7MJjuF5+Fl5lgF1aHanmk4PoCncZdxAXY4SO9PvT+GzLW61h9PCeIg==',
@p10=NULL,@p11=0,@p12=N'7ITLUKSUQKF76A2EXNARNT4CA5HVK2EM',@p13=0,@p14=N'Huu'
```

My c# class table:

```
namespace Repository.DomainModels
{
    [Table("AspNetUsers")]
    public class Customer: IdentityUser
    {
        public override string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my AspNetUsers table design:

[image]

Everything seems normal! The datatype of `[AspNetUsers].[Id]` column is `nvarchar(450)`, and `@p0` datatype is `nvarchar`.

But I get this error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '00ca2ac7-661d-4bc4-a967-4bf214fa9a29' to data type int.

My question is: why does SQL Server try to convert `nvarchar` to int in this situation? How can I fix it?

Please help me. Thank you very much

NOTE:
When I tried to harcode the `Insert into` with `@p0 = N'1'`.  It worked, no error message.  It even confused me more.  Why SQLSERVER try to convert `N'00ca2ac7-661d-4bc4-a967-4bf214fa9a29'`   to `Int`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't connect to a different database? Can you query it, e.g. `var userIds = UserManager.Users.Select(u => u.Id).ToList();` and then `var users = UserManager.Users.Where(u => userIds.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();`?

Comment: Naming your procedures with `SP_` can be a problem. Have a look at this https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: have you tried executing that query in `SSMS` ?

Comment: Try to refresh the database in SSMS and check whether the data type is nvarchar or not.  Then, right click the database in SSMS and create a New Query, execute the SQL query (get from the SQL server profiler), whether the query command  execute success or not? Based on your code and description, I create a sample on my side, the above query command and the insert function works well on my side.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the problem is on the SQL Server side. If I had to guess, your C# `model` has the Id property declared as an `int`. Please give more details about your model as part of the question.

Sidenote 1: A primary key with datatype `nvarchar(450)` is going to have dismal performance. If you're using guids as Ids, I suggest the guid type (`UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`) or at worst in your exact case `char(36)` if you're going to store it as text with the dashes.

Sidenote 2: You might want to obscure your email from the question

Comment: I declared the property as string type, not int.  I edited the question. Can you check again?

Comment: Another guess: Try your own model that does not extend `IdentityUser`. I know it's more convenient to not retype all that stuff but I've never used it this way and the override might be the issue here. Oh, and you are wiring your `Repository.DomainModels.Customer` as the identity model on startup, right?

Comment: I overrided the `IdentityUser.Id` property because the origional datatype is "TKey", and beacause I has this property refercenced by another table, so I have to make it as `string` type ( I try to avoid generic programming ).  And yes, I'm wiring `Repository.DomainModels.Customer` as the identity model on startup. Thank you anyway

Comment: The problem is `SQLSERVER`.  Can you check my updated?